# paperclip where to place the missing.png default image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I use paperclip in my app, but my controller tests are failing because of:

```
BlogsControllerTest#test_should_update_blog:
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for "/images/original/missing.png"
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/paperclip-3.5.2/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/registry.rb:19:in `handler_for'
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/paperclip-3.5.2/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/registry.rb:29:in `for'
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/paperclip-3.5.2/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:96:in `assign'
```

I'm not sure where I should place the `missing.png` image in my code, I tried in `public/assets/original/missing.png` but it doesn't seem to manage it.

Also there's something odd: I have a `paperclip.rb` initializer line:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = "/images/default_image.png"
```

but still the app is looking for the `missing.png`

UPDATE: ok I figured that the default_url was overridden in the model:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { big: "1200X630>", thumb: "150X150" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

I still don't know where to place the image.

UPDATE2:

the entire paperclip initializer:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:styles] = { thumb: "100x100#",  small: "200x200#",  screen: "800x600#"}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = "/images/missing.png"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":rails_root/public/assets/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = "/assets/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:hash_secret] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
Paperclip.registered_attachments_styles_path = "public/assets/paperclip_attachments2.yml"
```

UPDATE3: checking the paperclip code that actually rises the code, the exception is risen by [this piece of code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v3.5.2/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/registry.rb#L16-L19), which is basically testing all the adapters available, the one that looks like the closest to what I want to do is the [`fileAdapter`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v3.5.2/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/file_adapter.rb#L21) which tests if the string passed is a File.

I'm quite surprised from finding this, I thing I might be getting something wrong here. If I exchange the initializer line to:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = File.new "public/images/missing.png"
```

then the exception is different:

```
BlogsControllerTest#test_should_update_blog:
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<File:public/images/missing.png>
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/paperclip-3.5.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:33:in `block in interpolate'
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/paperclip-3.5.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:32:in `each'
```

UPDATE4: this is what the test looks like:

```
  test "should update blog" do
    put :update, id: @blog, blog: { 
      author_id: @blog.author_id, 
      body: @blog.body, 
      image: @blog.image, 
      title: @blog.title
    }
    assert_redirected_to blog_path(assigns(:blog))
  end

 test "should create blog" do
    assert_difference('Blog.count') do
      post :create, blog: { 
        author_id: @blog.author_id, 
        body: @blog.body, 
        image: @blog.image, 
        title: @blog.title }
    end

    assert_redirected_to blog_path(assigns(:blog))
  end
```

then:

```
@blog.image.class
=> Paperclip::Attachment
@blog.image.url
=> "/images/missing.png"
```

Comment: Where is 'has_attached_file :image' code?

Comment: Any updates @don guilio ?

Comment: the has_attached_file code is inside the blogs model

Comment: Put the image in /public/images/* and make your has_attached_file: default_url: "/image/*" This is wierd though, are you saving a default attachment if none is assigned?

Comment: What do you mean DDDDD? `:default_url` is commonly used ;)

Comment: I don't undertand, should I place a `*` in the default_url string? how will it know which image from that path to pick?

Comment: @dongiulio if it isn't a private thing please link your repo. I'll try to fix your issue on my own and give you feedback ;)

Comment: I'm afraid it is a private repo. thanks for the offer though, I've figured something odd in the paperclip code, I'm writing an update

Comment: No, where I put * you put the file name.

Comment: @DDDD thanks, already tried that.

Comment: HOw does your test look loke @dongiulio

Comment: gotcha! If you want model to use :default_url don't send `:image` in params. remove `image` from params and lets see how it goes`\

Comment: Fantastic, that solved it :) thanks a lot, please update your answer

Comment: I have exactly the same initializer line in `paperclip.rb`, but it says in the model: `has_attached_file :attachment` and no default_url overridden. Why is the image displayed as a link to `missing.png` and not as the png itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this line of code:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = "/images/default_image.png"
```

Paperclip is looking for images under  `/public/images/default_image.png`

#### update:

so you have defined style `big` and `thumb`. Paperclip will look for img in `public/images/thumb/default_image.png` or `public/images/big/default_image.png` depending what style will you call in `<% image_tag @model.image.url(:style) %>`.

#### update #2 (according to update #4 from author's question)

gotcha! If you want model to use `:default_url` don't send `:image` in params. remove image from params and lets see how it goes`

Comment: ok, I've removed the default image overriding and changed the initializer to `"/images/missing.png"` and placed an image under `/public/images/missing.png`, but I'm still getting the error `No handler found for "/images/missing.png"`

Comment: Just want to ensure: have u restarted rails server?

Comment: better sure than sorry :) : I'm seeing the issue when I run the unit tests with `rake test` the "server" is restarted at every attempt

Comment: Thanks, I've placed the file in these two dirs, and it didn't improve, I updated the question with the entire paperclip initializer

Comment: The error message says it is looking for missing.png inside the `public/images/original` folder, not just the `public/images` folder.

Comment: I just tested it on my own on new rails app and everything was working. I tested with setting up both default_url in initializer or controller. I think you still missed something. are you sure you placed it in `~/dir_to_your_app/public/images/big/missing.png`? If you want to define styles like `big` and `small` remember to call in `<% image_tag @model.image.url(:style)` as an argument, it is really important. What is more - what's your error msg right now?

Comment: so according to what @EgeErsoz pointed it might be possible that you don't specify `:style` in `@model.image.url(:style)` method. If you do that than it will look for image in `public/images/original`. solution is easy: specify `:style` in `.url()` method or add `missing.png` to dir `public/images/original/missing.png`

Comment: the view is not involved here, the exception is triggered by the `has_attached_file` validator in the model, I don't use the default image in my view.

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 5, I managed to work using **:style** in the path:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = "/images/folder/:style/missing.png"
```

and if, for example, this image doesn't exist:

```
<%= image_tag @photo.picture.url(:medium) %>
```

the result is

```
/images/folder/medium/missing.png
```